# Access control on smart contracts

Tags: evm, access

Is it possible to have access control on which smart contracts will be deployed in an EVM chain?
Or, how can we have authorized smart contracts on an EVM chain?

Answer (score 1):

On **public** EVM blockchains likes of `Ethereum, Avax, Polygon` you can't control who deploys smart contracts

However, on **private** EVM blockchains `Hyperleger Besu` you can control who can deploy on your blockchain if you control the nodes and who has access to them.

Comment: Is Aztec Network a private EVM?

Comment: I think Aztec Network is private in terms of who can see your transactions, not sure if they control who can deploy smart contracts there.

Comment: Do you know if smart contracts are even deployable inside the Aztec network? If so, are they **private smart contracts**?

Comment: As far as I can see from their documentation/webPage yes you can deploy smart contracts there. But I had never heard of the term (Private Smart Contracts). Only private and public blockchains.

Comment: Would you classify Aztec Network as a private EVM blockchain like Hyperleger and Besu, given that it is a zk roll-up?

Comment: I would classify Aztec Network as a **privacy** network. (User can send transactions anonymously). Same as in Hyperleger Besu. But as far as I can see, nothing is regulating who can or can't deploy smart contracts there.

Comment: Why doesn't it count as a blockchain? Aren't Hyperleger and Besu as well riding on Ethereum mainnet's gas txn rates?

Comment: On HyperLeger Besu you can determine gas price yourself (because it's your private network). Aztec Network is a blockchain with privacy features,  but it isn't private blockchain

Comment: What makes you say that Aztec is not a private blockchain when there's no way to glean info on transaction participants or their balances?

Comment: Aztec is a **public** blockchain with **privacy** features (as far as I can read from documentation) . HyperLeger besu is **private** blockchain with **privacy** features.  Ethereum is **public** blockchain with no **privacy** features. The difference is that on public blockchain anyone can deploy a smart contract. On private blockchain you need some kind of verification/precision before you are allowed to do so.

Comment: Ok public blockchain in the sense that it allows anyone to build on Aztec. Which has nothing to do with visibility of blockchain transactions; an obvious terminology misnomer.

Comment: Yes, I do feel we were running in circles here with the explanations.  Hahaha

Comment: In conclusion, Aztec Network is a **public blockchain** open to anyone wanting to build **private smart contracts**

Answer (score 0):

There is a commonly used library from OpenZeppelin called Ownable that allows to easily do access control.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol

You can also look into role granting if you need more roles and access levels.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol

Hopes this helps!